# Facebook FQL with file_get_contents returns empty array

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm echoing the Facebook comments for my website's urls directly in my website using a FQL script. However, some urls return an empty array even though if I access the Facebook API directly I can see them full with comments. This is happening only for the latest urls. This is the code I use:

```
$queries = array('q1' => 'select post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time from comment where object_id in (select comments_fbid from link_stat where url ="'.$url.'")',
             'q2' => 'select post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time from comment where object_id in (select post_fbid from #q1)',
             'q3' => 'select name, id, url, pic_square, username from profile where id in (select fromid from #q1) or id in (select fromid from #q2)',
             'q4' => 'select uid, first_name from user where uid in (select fromid from #q1) or uid in (select fromid from #q2)',
             );
$result = (file_get_contents('http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?format=json-strings&method=fql.multiquery&queries='.urlencode(json_encode($queries)));
```

Now, If I echo the $result variable, I see this:

[{"name":"q1","fql_result_set":[]},{"name":"q2","fql_result_set":[]},{"name":"q3","fql_result_set":[]},{"name":"q4","fql_result_set":[]}]

Even though I see the fql_result_set full in the API url (api.facebook.com etc. etc.). Is there someone who can explain me this strange behavior? :-)

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint http://api.facebook.com is deprecated. Use https://graph.facebook.com instead. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/#fql as reference.

Also, you need to make sure that the references between the queries are correct. Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/#operations and read about the JSONPATH syntax you can use.

Altered queries:

```
$queries = array('q1' => 'select post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time from comment where object_id in (select comments_fbid from link_stat where url ="'.$url.'")',
             'q2' => 'select post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time from comment where object_id in ({result=q1:$.data.*.post_fbid})',
             'q3' => 'select name, id, url, pic_square, username from profile where id in ({result=q1:$.data.*.fromid}) or id in ({result=q2:$.data.*.fromid})',
             'q4' => 'select uid, first_name from user where uid in ({result=q1:$.data.*.fromid}) or uid in ({result=q2:$.data.*.fromid})',
             );
```

What I don't understand with your queries:

- q2 is more or less a duplicate of q1
- q3 information could also be retrieved by altering q4

Comment: Hi Tobi, I tried to change the URL (from api to graph) but I still have the same result: [{"name":"q1","fql_result_set":[]},{"name":"q2","fql_result_set":[]},{"name":"q3","fql_result_set":[]},{"name":"q4","fql_result_set":[]}] , even though the fql_result_set is not empty in the url

Comment: Have you issed the requests one by one? And they work?